# Extract XML in MySql with dynamic XPATH

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath

I have two tables in a legacy database. One of them contains a field containing some xml. This other table contains the tags that constitutes the xml.

For example consider a table with a list of languages (e.g. `en`, `fr`, `it`) and a table with a field like

```
<en>Something</en><fr>Quelque chose</fr><it>Qualcosa</it>
```

I would like to extract all the translations. I have a query that goes like

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(extractvalue(table.field, languages.sigla))
FROM table, languages
GROUP BY table.id
```

But I get the following error

```
[HY000][1105] Only constant XPATH queries are supported
```

I guess this is a limitation of MySql (I'm usign version 5.6). Is there any other way to obtain what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and found an easy workaround in that blog post : http://sql-debug.blogspot.com/2012/05/extractvalue-only-constant-xpath.html

The solution is really surprising, but as silly as it can seem, it works perfectly...

It consists in creating a function that only "wraps" the ExtractValue function, in order to give it the xpath as an already generated string.

```
delimiter ##
create function exv(xml text, xpath text) returns text charset utf8 
begin 
return cast(extractvalue(xml, xpath) as char); 
end ##
delimiter ;
```

And then, just replace *extractvalue* with *exv* in the query you tried to run when you got this [HY000][1105] error.

Of course, this workaround has a performance cost...

Answer (score 0):

One option you can try is (adjust as needed):

```sql
mysql> SELECT
    ->     GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT ExtractValue(@`xml`, \'', `der`.`lang`, '\') `lang`' SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') INTO @`query`
    -> FROM (
    ->     SELECT 'en' `lang`
    ->     UNION
    ->     SELECT 'fr'
    ->     UNION
    ->     SELECT 'it'
    -> ) `der`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @`xml` := '<en>Something</en><fr>Quelque chose</fr><it>Qualcosa</it>';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @`query` := CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`der`.`lang`)
    '>                         FROM (', @`query`, ') `der`');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`query`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE `stmt`;
+----------------------------------+
| GROUP_CONCAT(`der`.`lang`)       |
+----------------------------------+
| Something,Quelque chose,Qualcosa |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```